# Russian roulette with a gun that spins randomly. What are the chances of never being shot and how to express the diminishing chances of that outcome?

Tags: probability, random

My math is bad but I'm intrigued by a problem.

I was part of this discussion earlier today. In an imaginary Russian Roulette game, there's the standard 6 holes and single bullet in the gun, but once the trigger is pressed, the cylinder's spin is random. Both the direction and amount of holes it will move are random.

Some people where adamant in claiming you can press that trigger a billion times and not get shot. That seems to me, impossible, either in principle or in practice. Now see, the points I stood for were:

1. It seems impossible, **in theory**, for that bullet not to
   ever be fired, because if the cylinder's spin is truly random, it
   will eventually land on every single hole, on average, 1 out of
   every 6 times. I'm saying this based purely on the intuition that
   given such a small set, an algorithm avoiding one or more specific
   elements expresses a predictable pattern and can't be truly random.
2. If I'm wrong and it's theoretically possible for the bullet to
   never be fired, it feels that **in practice** it's not.  It seems to me that the chances the bullet will not be fired
   are inversely proportional to the number of trigger pulls.  That is,
   if the trigger is never pulled, there's a 100% chance the bullet
   won't be fired. If if it's pulled once, that certainty ***has*** to
   go down. Given enough trigger pulls then it goes down enough to
   reach and then cross the threshold under which it's a
   positive integer. Then either it becomes a decimal smaller than 1 or a
   negative integer, at some point that value will no longer be relevant and one
   can assert the bullet has been fired.

So I have 2 problems here that you can help me with

1. I'm bad at math and can't prove either point
2. If either one is provable, I don't know what's the way to express it concisely. The simplest explanation I came up with is the trigger pull x certainty relation I came up with.

EDIT:
I''d like to thank you all who answered and commented. This had left me super intrigued and excited, and was oersonally very important to me, because even if I used to be one of the worst in class for math, it showed me that given an interesting wrapping and enough logical thinking, one can get far in solving such a problem.

I wish one day I'll adult.life will guve me enough of a break so that I have time to priperly learn math, the thing is amazing.

Comment: It's inaccurate to say it will eventually land on every hole unless you have infinite tries. If you only have finitely many, say before the gun falls apart or can't fire anymore, the possibility of always missing exists. It's just small.

Comment: Just to confirm your intuition, $\left(\frac 56\right)^{25}=0.0105$ so there is just a hair over a $1\%$ chance that you will survive $25$ rounds.    And  $\left(\frac 56\right)^{50}=0.000109885$  so there is just over a $.01\%$ chance of surviving $50$ rounds.  But the probability never gets to $0$ for any finite number of rounds.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks, I get your point. It's like this possibility can get orders of magnitude smaller, but relative to a finite number of attempts, it won't cease to exist. I think this is implicit in my question by leaving the theoretical possibility of this open to question.

But thaks, the way you phrased it made clear what's going on with that point.

Comment: @lulu thanks, that's precisely what I wanted. I mathematical way of showing that even if the probability is there that you'll never hit the bullet, in practice the likelihood is so small after so many tries that you can just assume you'll get the bullet.

Thanks, I'm so happy for this, I learned a lot from this otherwise pointless discussion.

Comment: It is possible that the discussion you were having was more nuanced than may appear on the surface. You might want to learn that statistically impossible events [may occur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely#Illustrative_examples) and that your intuition about "landing on every single hole" is an informal expression of the  [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Comment: Interestingly, if you play such a Russian Roulette, you will eventually kill yourself for [the same reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Example_2) infinitely many monkeys will produce Shakespeare within a finite amount of time.

Comment: Another way of thinking of it - if you pull the trigger once a minute, your expected lifetime will be 6 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pro(nevrr)=$(\frac{5}{6})^n$ for n tries.  As you see it gets smaller as n increases.

Powers that be will kick you off.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that since the spin of the wheel is random and in any direction so there is always a chance that in finite number of shots one can expect to survive. And $P(\text{surviving $n$ shots})= (\frac56)^n$.

However it is quite visible that as the no of shots increases the probability of surviving the shot also decreases but it will never going to make $0$ for finite $n$.
But as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the probability of surviving $\rightarrow  0$.